# Node Js error Cannot read property 'reduce' of undefined with SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, stripe-payments, nodejs-server, glitch-framework

I have node js server hosted into Glitch and I am using express version . I also added the packages for Stripe and cros . I am making HTTP request form IOS app which is developed into swiftUI (Shopping cart app). I have added the stripe into my SwiftUI project. I am following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=De7EL_1jv0c. Here is the glitch server link https://glitch.com/ to host the node js server . I using the public key during the request  to exchange the secret key. The problem is I have having this error into Glitch server console ..

**(node:1314) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'reduce' of undefined
at calculateOrderAmount (/app/server.js:11:23)**

Tis function produce the error saying the reduce not be read . This function calculating the total .

```
const calculateOrderAmount = items => {

  const total = items.reduce((previous, current) => {
    return previous.price + current.price
  })
  return total * 100;
};
```

Here is the node js server code ..

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
// This is your test secret API key.
const stripe = require("stripe")("your public key form stripe");

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(express.json());

const calculateOrderAmount = items => {
  
  const total = items.reduce((previous, current) => {
    return previous.price + current.price
  })
  return total * 100;
};

app.post("/create-payment-intent", async (req, res) => {
  const { items } = req.body;

  // Create a PaymentIntent with the order amount and currency
  const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
    amount: calculateOrderAmount(items),
    currency: "gbp",
    // In the latest version of the API, specifying the `automatic_payment_methods` parameter is optional because Stripe enables its functionality by default.
    automatic_payment_methods: {
      enabled: true,
    },
  });

 res.send({
    clientSecret: paymentIntent.client_secret,
  });
});

app.listen(8080, () => console.log("Node server listening on port 8080!"));
```

```
Here is my Swiftui main.app code ..

import SwiftUI
import Firebase
import Stripe

@main
struct DemoEcommerceApp: App {
    @StateObject var viewModel = AuthViewModel()
    @StateObject var order = Order()

    init() {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        StripeAPI.defaultPublishableKey = "Stripe public key"
    }
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
           ContentViewOne()
                .environmentObject(viewModel)
                .environmentObject(order)
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the product.

```
 @Published var products = [Product]()
```

Json.

```
// MARK: - Product
struct Product: Codable, Hashable, Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let title: String
    var price, quantity, total: Int
    let discountPercentage: Double
    let discountedPrice: Int
    let thumbnail: String
}
```

Here is my private function to start making payment ..

```
extension OrderView {

    private func startCheckout(completion: @escaping (String?) -> Void) {

        let url = URL(string: "https://rogue-quartz-ounce.glitch.me/create-payment-intent")!

        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.httpBody = try! JSONEncoder().encode(order.products)

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in

            guard let data = data, error == nil,
                  (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode == 200
            else {
                completion(nil)
                print(error?.localizedDescription)
                return
            }

            let checkoutIntentResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode(CheckoutIntentResponse.self, from: data)
            completion(checkoutIntentResponse?.clientSecret)

        }.resume()

    }
}
```

Here is my pay function ..

```
extension OrderView {

    private func pay() {

        guard let clientSecret = PaymentConfig.shared.paymentIntentClientSecret else {
            return
        }

        let paymentIntentParams = STPPaymentIntentParams(clientSecret: clientSecret)
        paymentIntentParams.paymentMethodParams = paymentMethodParams

        paymentGatewayController.submitPayment(intent: paymentIntentParams) { status, intent, error in

            switch status {
                case .failed:
                    message = "Failed"
                case .canceled:
                    message = "Cancelled"
                case .succeeded:
                    message = "Your payment has been successfully completed!"
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Here is the API response code ..

```
import Foundation


struct CheckoutIntentResponse: Decodable {
    let clientSecret: String
}
```

Here is the singleton class ..

```
import Foundation

class PaymentConfig {

    var paymentIntentClientSecret: String?
    static var shared: PaymentConfig = PaymentConfig()

    private init() { }
}
```

Here is the gateway controller ..

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Stripe

class PaymentGatewayController: UIViewController {


    func submitPayment (intent : STPPaymentIntentParams, completion: @escaping (STPPaymentHandlerActionStatus, STPPaymentIntent?, NSError?) -> Void) {
        let paymentHandler = STPPaymentHandler.shared()
        paymentHandler.confirmPayment(intent, with: self) { (status, intent, error) in
            completion(status, intent, error)
        }
    }
}

extension PaymentGatewayController: STPAuthenticationContext {
    func authenticationPresentingViewController() -> UIViewController {
        return self
    }
}
```

Here is the swiftui view code ..

```
@State private var message: String = ""
    @State private var isSuccess: Bool = false
    @State private var paymentMethodParams: STPPaymentMethodParams?
    let paymentGatewayController = PaymentGatewayController()

       var body: some View {

        NavigationStack {
            
            List {
                Section {
// Stripe Credit Card TextField Here
             STPPaymentCardTextField.Representable.init(paymentMethodParams:        $paymentMethodParams)
                    } header: {
                        Text("Payment Information")
                    }
                    HStack {
                        Spacer()
                        Button("Pay") {
                            startCheckout { clientSecret in

                                PaymentConfig.shared.paymentIntentClientSecret = clientSecret
                                self.pay()
                            }

                        }.buttonStyle(.plain)
                        Spacer()
                    }

                }
                HStack {
                    Text(message)
                        .font(.headline)
                }
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Cannot read property 'reduce' of undefined at calculateOrderAmount` means that your `items` is undefined when passed into `calculateOrderAmount`, likely because `items` is undefined in the `body` of your request:

```
const { items } = req.body
```

this is where you need to debug, and determine what your `req.body` contains, and how to change it.

I'm not familiar with Swift HTTP requests, but looking at the code you shared it looking like the body is set here:

```
request.httpBody = try! JSONEncoder().encode(order.products)
```

It's not obvious if/how this would set `items` so I suggest looking here first. Perhaps this should be something like `{ items: order.products }`?

Comment: This is the array of products

Comment: @Published var products = [Product]()

Comment: Sure, but the `/create-payment-intent` endpoint is expecting `items` and `calculateOrderAmount` then expects that to be an array of objects each having `price`. So you need to ensure your client code is passing data that fits that expectation, or you need to change the server code to match your client data.